# I'd like to have the choice to exit instead of entering input

Tags: python, exit, prompt, sys

Here is a program to copy one directory to a new path, but regardless of the program's purpose, I'd like to know how to simply exit upon pressing enter instead of putting input.

Here is my attempt using `sys.exit`. When, at the first prompt ('Which dir to copy?'), I simply press enter (entering no data to prompt), and it still asks me the second question ('And to where may i ask??>>)
I would like to instead exit the program after pressing enter at the first prompt.

```
print "\n" * 5
print "\033[1m" + "Be Careful."
print "\033[0m"
print  "\n\tThis program will make changes to your directories.\n\tProceed with caution."
print "\n" * 5
print "\n" * 2
print "Press enter at any prompt to exit."
print "\n" * 5



from sys import exit

import shutil, os
os.chdir('/Users/User/')
butt = raw_input('Which dir you want copy??>> ')
whr = raw_input('And to where may i ask??>> ')
if butt == '' or whr == '':
    exit(0)
else:
    shutil.copytree(butt, whr)



import os
inputfolder = raw_input('What\'s the path bro???>>>> ')
for foldarName, subfolders, filnames in os.walk(inputfolder):
    print('The current folder is ' + foldarName)

    for sub in subfolders:
        print('SUBFOLDER OF ' + foldarName + ': ' + sub)
    for filna in filnames:
        print('FILE INSIDE ' + foldarName + ': ' + filna)

    print ('')
```

Comment: Hi Carles.  I just tried this and am getting the exact same results.  It doesn't cause it to exit, it simply goes to the next prompt.  Thanks

Comment: You don't check and exit until after the *second* question, why did this behaviour surprise you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python runs line by line, therefore checking to see if the variable *butt* is empty until **after** asking the second question won't have your desired result.

```
butt = raw_input('Which dir you want copy??>> ')
if butt == ''
    exit(0)

whr = raw_input('And to where may i ask??>> ')
if whr == '':
    exit(0)

shutil.copytree(butt, whr) # doesn't require an else statement
```

Also, a more efficient way of doing this would be

```
if not butt:
    exit(0)
```

Comment: Perfect.  Makes complete sense.